# Laravel cURL won't write cookie file

Tags: php, curl, cookies, laravel-5

I have found many questions like mine, unfortunately without a working for me solution. I have created a function for crawling websites, but for some websites I need to set some cookies to get the relevant content. 
My website is using framework Laravel 5.2 and the problem is that it does not save a cookie file to the storage path (or to the public too).

Years ago on non Laravel site I was using the same function and there was no problem to create the cookies file.

Here is the function:

```
function getFileContentByCurl($strURL, $objPost = "", $strReferrer = "", $objHeaders = "", $strCookie = "") {

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        $cookie_file = storage_path('app/cookies.txt');

        if($strCookie) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
        }   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 65536);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

        if($strCookie != "") {curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);}
        if($strReferrer != "") {curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $strReferrer);}
        if($objHeaders != "") {curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $objHeaders);}
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        if($objPost != ""){curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $objPost);}
        $returned = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        sleep(5);
        return $returned;

}
```

I have tried to put an empty file in the storage directory, but it does not write in it. Have checked if the file is writable and it is.

Comment: can I suggest not using `CURLOPT_COOKIE` when you're using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`+`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`. That file is supposed to automate the retention of cookies.

Comment: @Scuzzy i have removed it, but still it does not write in the cookie file

Comment: what does `is_writeable()` say about that folder/path?

Comment: @Scuzzy if i place there an empty file, it says that's writable, but it does not write in it anything. Or if there is no file, it does not create it itself

Comment: And your code is definetly hitting those cookie file/jar options to active (ie the logic around `if($strCookie) {` is ok?)

Comment: @Scuzzy yes it is

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest is reducing the code to the smallest possible solution where cookies file/jar will work, and then building back up from there.

**curl.php**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/cookie.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

**cookie.php**

```
<?php
if( !isset($_COOKIE['testcookie']))
{
  setcookie('testcookie',date('r'),time()+10);
}
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: that thing is working. But if i change the url from http://localhost/cookie.php to the website i want to crawl it does not work. Why is that ?

Comment: Then it would mean there's no cookies being received by curl by that first request, because that's all my test script is doing, setting the cookie headers.

Comment: But the website has cookies accordingly Firebug ?

Comment: so that's definitely after clearing cookies or using a private window and looking at the very first http request? I'm not sure I've got any further advice without knowing the site you indent to scrape.

Comment: This is the website: http://www.betexplorer.com/results/soccer/?year=2017&month=12&day=22 Unfortunately when is set the date i get totally different results. I will appreciate your help !

Comment: That URL doesn't return any cookies, tested by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`, I also had to add user agent detection. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0');` My guess is the cookie is clientn side javascript.

Comment: yes, user agent is needed. So what is your opinion, can it be scraped with php and curl ?

Comment: I had no problems scraping that first URL exactly as is, but spidering subsequentn pages, looks like there's too much javascript.